# Why does HTTP is text based and not some compressed method ? Why isn't JS compressed?

Tags: javascript, http, compression

I sniffed some packets off my Google Chrome browser - and I found out that:

1. HTTP requests are send as text - actually sending 'GET BLABLABLA'
2. JS is received as text
3. HTML \ images etc is transferred in some compressed method.

My question is - Why HTTP and JS is transferred without any compression ?
I think that a fully form HTTP request can be compressed to about 3 ~ 5 bytes not including cookies and given that page picking is also compressed (e.g site.com/thisisanicefile.html > site.com/ABC)
Also - why is JS transferred as plain text and not as an array of Tokens (programming languages are converted to an array of Tokens before execution - same goes for scripting languages) ?
Thanks - Mark

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol): well, that's how the protocol is defined. The protocol is text-based. Makes it simple to implement without having to worry about things like endianness.

Contents (html, javascript, images, ...) can be sent compressed, that's a matter of encoding "negotiation" between the browser and the server (both need to support it). See the [HTTP Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) page on Wikipedia for a run-down on how it works.

Transferring JavaScript in a pre-processed form (some kind of bytecode) would require that bytecode form to be standardized and implemented in all browsers, and would provide very little benefit. The size difference versus compressed, minified JavaScript would likely not be stellar (after all, you'd be sending the same quantity of *information*, so a good compression algorithm should make the size of both practically identical).

You'd also need to compile the JS code before you make it available on your webserver (one more build/deploy task), or compile it on the fly (CPU waste), and that wouldn't prevent the need for a full-blown source code interpreter on the browser without restricting the language (no more `eval` / code generation on the frontend if it cannot process JS source).

Comment: You forgot to mention you can gzip javascript.

Comment: That's included in the http contents compression. I don't think javascript is special in regard - it can be gzipped like any other content.

Answer (score 2):

The **HTTP header** is never compressed -- there's just no protocol for HTTP header compression. I suppose there's no need, it's not like the header is a very large part of your 100kB+ website.

For individual HTTP requests, the behaviour depends on the server configuration and on the client. If the client doesn't say that it is happy to accept gzip/deflated content, the server won't compress. If the client does say so, then the the server **may** choose to compress depending on its configuration. (E.g. for Apache, you need so set up `mod_deflate`).

For example, it'd be perfectly reasonable for the server not to compress JPEGs and PNGs, on account of them already being compressed. The server may also not choose to compress anything handled by the PHP handler and prefer to leave it up to the handler to compress or not. (So for example if the handler delivers a PDF, it can compress, but if it delivers an MP3, it won't.)

Short answer: It all depends.

Answer (score 0):

> ...premature optimization is the root of all evil

(c) [you know who](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Headers should be always as text -- only bodies could gzipped.
Js bodies also could be gzipped -- see you webserver settings.